# Unable to Access MS Access database on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: c#, ms-access, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a software that I wrote on c# that reads and writes to an MS Access database (its in .mdb format). This database is located in the same installation folder. It works fine on windows XP. In windows 7 and 8.1, it also works ok when I set windows compatibility for the program to XP and set the UAC security setting in the control panel to its lowest level. My issue is with windows 2008 R2. The software runs but when it tries to read from the db, I get an exception (with no specific message apart from "software winUI.exe has stopped working"). WinUI.exe is the name of the executable.

This is definitely a database permission access issue or a missing component that may need to be installed in order for the c# program to be able to read from the database. On Windows 2008 R2 I have tried:

> Setting UAC to lowest level.
>   Sharing the folder that the database file resides in an allowing it to be available to all.
>   Setting the database file to allow users to read and write to it.
>   Compiling the software to target a 64bit systems as this is what Windows server 2008 R2 is.
>   Since the machine has office 2010 installed, I use this connection string: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.mdb;
>   Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;
>   I am logged in as the administrator when doing this.

None of these measures work. If anyone has seen this kind of an issue, please advice me on what else could be missing. Thanks

Comment: I guess you should have the database under `%ProgramData%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%`, or install outside `%ProgramFiles%`

Comment: This may not be the issue since even when I copy the installation folder elsewhere, like to another drive on the same machine outside the %ProgramFiles% folder, I still get the same effect. The software runs ok but fails when it tries to access the database